# Find a specific number in a string

Tags: vba, string

I'm using an IF THEN statement to determine if a string contains a specific number. For example, the string = 1, 9, 13. I'm trying to isolate strings that contain the single number "3". However, when I use Like "3", or Like "*3*", I also get the results back that contain 13. How do I use wildcards to do this?

Comment: You might want to look into String's split method.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is just a list of numbers in the form you have shown ...
"n1, n2, n3, n4"

... then you can use VBA's `Like` function as follows:

```
Debug.Print " 1, 7, 5, 13," Like "*[ ]3,*" 'matches 3 but not 13
```

If your string is arbitrary, then this is actually a regular expression question, and you'll need to decide if this a route you want to go down. Something like the following works at the [Regex Tester Page](http://[https://www.regextester.com/]):

```
/\b3\b/g
```

There's a useful [VBA Regex Regular Expressions Guide](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-regex-regular-expressions-guide/) which shows you how to use syntax like this, including how to set a reference to the additional library that you need for it to work.